# Sort by postmeta on when searching

Tags: query, search, post-meta

I'm trying to sort by total_sales when searching, I have this till now but does not seem to do anything

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    if (    !is_admin() // Target only front end queries
         && $q->is_main_query() // Target the main query only
         && ( $q->is_search() )
    ) {
        $q->set( 'meta_key', 'total_sales' );
        $q->set( 'order',    'DESC'         );
        $q->set( 'orderby',  'meta_value_num'  );
    }
});
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code, as far as I can tell, but it does make a couple of assumptions: That total sales is post meta and the meta key is exactly `total_sales`, and that the 'search' you're performing is a proper WordPress search (with `?s=` in the URL) and not something custom or a secondary query. Are you certain both those things are true?

Comment: URL looks like this ?s=abstract+pattern&post_type=product and total_sales is in postmeta table, every product has it since I already sort them by this but in product-category, and I want same for searches

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that I had a plugin installed that deals with the searches, it's called Better Search.

```
function query_1($query){
    $query .= ",wp_postmeta.meta_value as total_saless ";
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'bsearch_posts_match_field', 'query_1' );

function query_2($query){
    $query .= "AND wp_postmeta.meta_key='total_sales' ";
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'bsearch_posts_where', 'query_2' );

function query_3($query){
    $query = " CAST(total_saless AS INTEGER) > 99999 DESC, score DESC ";
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'bsearch_posts_orderby', 'query_3' );
```

All I had to do was to hook into it.